# PHP write to file without last newline

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I want to read a CSV data file, load it into an array, edit it and write it back to a file. I have been able to accomplish this a single iteration with examples here on Stackoverflow! Thanks.

The trouble is when I write the new data back to the file, both methods I have tried to write the edited Array back to the file add an newline at the end the file. This creates an issue when loading the CSV file data a 2nd time. The 2nd read causes an empty Index in the Array that causes an error when writing the file.

Example #1:

```
foreach($editArray as $row) {
    $writeStuff = implode(",", $row);
    fwrite($file_handle, $writeStuff);
    fwrite($file_handle, "\n");
}
```

Example #2:

```
foreach ($editArray as $row) {
    fputcsv($file_handle, $row);
}
```

This is the original csv data:

```
1/1/16,Yes,No
1/2/16,No,Yes
```

When written using the above it produces this data with the added newline:

```
1/1/16,Yes,No
1/2/16,No,Yes
```

This extra new line creates an issue when reading the file a 2nd time. I get an error on both the `fputcsv()` or `implode()`. I believe it is because the empty Index caused by the newline when I read the file the 2nd time after the first write.

I could use a for loop with a conditional on the last `fwrite()` in the `implode()` Example #1, but that would seem clunky and not the way to do it.

Maybe there is a completely different way to handle this?

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: I don't see any way that can add an extra newline, unless the last element of `$editArray` ends with a newline while the other elements don't.

Comment: In the first example you are explicitly writing a newline in the last statement. Is this the reason you are getting an extra newline at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of [`fputcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

> fputcsv() formats a line (passed as a fields array) as CSV and write it (terminated by a newline) to the specified file handle.

Being that all lines are terminated by newline, you will have an extra blank line at the end of the file

You should apply a fix for the second read, where the last line creates issues, by checking if the line is empty before processing.

Comment: Thank you to both responses. Upon the recommendation checking before processing, I came up with two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent adding a new line at the end of the file, you could build your data set with new lines where you need them (and where you don't) then write it once:

```
$writeStuff = [];
foreach($editArray as $row) {
    $writeStuff[] = implode(',', $row);
}
fwrite($file_handle, implode(PHP_EOL, $writeStuff));
```

Also, I'm not sure how you load the file, but you could always skip empty lines - here's an example:

```
$editArray = file('your_filename.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES |  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the recommendation, I looked for a solution when reading and loading the file rather than when I wrote the file.

These are the solutions I came up with.

First Option:

```
while(! feof($file_handle)) {
    $tmp = fgetcsv($file_handle);
    if($tmp != NULL) {
        $myArray[] = $tmp;
    }
}
```

fgetcsv returns a NULL if the line is empty.

Second Option. Ditch the fgetcsv() for file(). It ignores the empty newline without testing.

```
$data_Array = file($file);

foreach($$data_Array as $key) {
    $myArray[] = explode(",", $key);
}
```

This seems to work. Additionally the example given earlier with implode() and PHP_EOL seems to work also. I may be missing something, but these work for now.